# How to show spectrum, when music playing?

Tags: html, html5-canvas, web-audio-api

I need to show spectrum analyzer, when music is playing. 
Now, the spetrum drawing separated with audio player.
If file ready (after loading with XHR) and song is playing, synchronously draving the spectrum.

```js
  var audioBuffer;
    var sourceNode;
    var analyser;
    var javascriptNode;
       var actx = new(AudioContext || webkitAudioContext)(), tid,
    url = "https://cdn.rawgit.com/epistemex/free-music-for-test-and-demo/master/music/kf_colibris.mp3";

    var ctx = $("#canvas").get()[0].getContext("2d");
    var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,300);
    gradient.addColorStop(1,'#000000');
    gradient.addColorStop(0.75,'#ff0000');
    gradient.addColorStop(0.25,'#ffff00');
    gradient.addColorStop(0,'#ffffff');

    setupAudioNodes();
    
    function setupAudioNodes() {
        // setup a javascript node
        javascriptNode = actx.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);
        // connect to destination, else it isn't called
        javascriptNode.connect(actx.destination);
        // setup a analyzer
        analyser = actx.createAnalyser();
        analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.3;
        analyser.fftSize = 512;

        // create a buffer source node
        sourceNode = actx.createBufferSource();
        sourceNode.connect(analyser);
        analyser.connect(javascriptNode);
        sourceNode.connect(actx.destination);
    }

    // load the specified sound

    function playSound(buffer) {
        sourceNode.buffer = buffer;
        sourceNode.start(0);
    }

    // log if an error occurs
    function onError(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }

    // when the javascript node is called
    // we use information from the analyzer node
    // to draw the volume
    javascriptNode.onaudioprocess = function() {

        // get the average for the first channel
        var array =  new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array);

        // clear the current state
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 325);

        // set the fill style
        ctx.fillStyle=gradient;
        drawSpectrum(array);

    }


    function drawSpectrum(array) {
        for ( var i = 0; i < (array.length); i++ ){
            var value = array[i];

            ctx.fillRect(i*5,325-value,3,325);
            //  console.log([i,value])
        }
    };

// old draw --------------------------------------------------------


// STEP 1: Load audio file using AJAX ----------------------------------
loadXHR(url, decode);

tid = setInterval(function() {document.querySelector("div").innerHTML += "."}, 500);

function loadXHR(url, callback) {
  try {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    xhr.onerror = function() {console.log("Network error.")};
    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (xhr.status === 200) callback(xhr.response);
      else console.log("Loading error:" + xhr.statusText);
    };
    xhr.send();
  } catch (err) {console.log(err.message)}
}

// STEP 2: Decode the audio file ---------------------------------------
function decode(buffer) {
  clearInterval(tid);
  document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = "Decoding file...";
  actx.decodeAudioData(buffer, split);
}

// STEP 3: Split the buffer --------------------------------------------
function split(abuffer) {

  document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = "Splitting...";

  setTimeout(function() {   // to allow DOM to update status-text

    // calc number of segments and segment length
    var channels = abuffer.numberOfChannels,
        duration = abuffer.duration
        rate = abuffer.sampleRate,
        segmentLen = 10,
        count = Math.floor(duration / segmentLen),
        offset = 0,
       // block = 10 * rate;
       block = abuffer.length;

  //  while(count--) {
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(bufferToWave(abuffer, offset, block));
      var audio = new Audio(url);
      audio.controls = true;
      audio.volume = 0.5;
      audio.autoplay = true;
      document.body.appendChild(audio);
      //offset += block;
  //  }  

    document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = "Ready!";
  }, 60)


 playSound(abuffer);


}

// Convert a audio-buffer segment to a Blob using WAVE representation
function bufferToWave(abuffer, offset, len) {

  var numOfChan = abuffer.numberOfChannels,
      length = len * numOfChan * 2 + 44,
      buffer = new ArrayBuffer(length),
      view = new DataView(buffer),
      channels = [], i, sample,
      pos = 0;
      
  // write WAVE header
  setUint32(0x46464952);                         // "RIFF"
  setUint32(length - 8);                         // file length - 8
  setUint32(0x45564157);                         // "WAVE"
  
  setUint32(0x20746d66);                         // "fmt " chunk
  setUint32(16);                                 // length = 16
  setUint16(1);                                  // PCM (uncompressed)
  setUint16(numOfChan);
  setUint32(abuffer.sampleRate);
  setUint32(abuffer.sampleRate * 2 * numOfChan); // avg. bytes/sec
  setUint16(numOfChan * 2);                      // block-align
  setUint16(16);                                 // 16-bit (hardcoded in this demo)
  
  setUint32(0x61746164);                         // "data" - chunk
  setUint32(length - pos - 4);                   // chunk length
  
  // write interleaved data
  for(i = 0; i < abuffer.numberOfChannels; i++)
    channels.push(abuffer.getChannelData(i));
  
  while(pos < length) {
    for(i = 0; i < numOfChan; i++) {             // interleave channels
      sample = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, channels[i][offset])); // clamp
      sample = (0.5 + sample < 0 ? sample * 32768 : sample * 32767)|0; // scale to 16-bit signed int
      view.setInt16(pos, sample, true);          // update data chunk
      pos += 2;
    }
    offset++                                     // next source sample
  }

  // create Blob
  return new Blob([buffer], {type: "audio/wav"});
  
  function setUint16(data) {
    view.setUint16(pos, data, true);
    pos += 2;
  }
  
  function setUint32(data) {
    view.setUint32(pos, data, true);
    pos += 4;
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="325" style="display: block;"></canvas>

<div>Loading.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT use a ScriptProcessorNode's onaudioprocess to do visual updates - skip the ScriptProcessor altogether, and use requestAnimationFrame to call getByteFrequencyData and do visual updates.

Comment: Help me please here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30348906/ff-and-opera-not-open-encoded-files-with-url-blob